# Get Currently Playing Track in BeatsMedia API?

Tags: beatsmusic

Perhaps I am missing it... but is there a method in the BeatsMusic API that allows me to find out which song a user is currently listening to?

https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The server does not track what is being played.